# Store each loop, and output to table at loop completion

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to output the results of some SSL discovery scanning as a table for reporting purposes, and I having some issues with parsing that data in the way I want.

I want the output to look like this:

```
IP Address    Common Name             Valid To
------------  ----------------------  ----------
10.0.255.250   ex.example.com  2017/02/09
10.0.255.251   localhost      2009/07/04
10.0.255.252    ex.example2.com     2016/05/24
```

instead it looks like this.

```
IP Address    Common Name             Valid To
------------  ----------------------  ----------
10.0.255.250   ex.example.com  2017/02/09
IP Address    Common Name    Valid To
------------  -------------  ----------
10.0.255.251   localhost      2009/07/04
None
IP Address    Common Name    Valid To
------------  -------------  ----------
10.0.255.252    ex.example2.com     2016/05/2
```

I've been trying to use a while loop to sort this out and haven't had any luck. It appears to be less of a "while" loop and more of a "for each" loop.

```
def tabulateText():
    loop = True
    while loop == True:
        with open("testinput.txt", "r") as text_file:
            for line in text_file:
                if "end" in line:
                    loop = False
                elif "IP Address =" in line:
                    start = line.find('IP Address = ')
                    endline = line.find('\n', start)
                    ip = line[start+13:endline]
                    cert = SSLmon(ip)
                    Col1 = ip
                    FCS2 = cert.find('commonName')
                    FCE2 = cert.find('/', FCS2)
                    FCS2b = cert.find('commonName')
                    FCE2b = cert.find('\n', FCS2b)
                    Colopt2 = cert[FCS2+11:FCE2]
                    Colopt2b = cert[FCS2b+11:FCE2b]
                    Col2 = cert[FCS2+11:FCE2] if len(Colopt2) < len(Colopt2b) else cert[FCS2b+11:FCE2b]
                    FCS3 = cert.find('Not valid after:')
                    FCE3 = cert.find('T', FCS3)
                    Col3 = cert[FCS3+18:FCE3].replace('-', '/')
                    column = Col1[n], Col2[n], Col3[n]
                    print(tabulate([column], headers=['IP Address', 'Common Name', 'Valid To']))
                else:
                    pass

print(tabulateText())
print(tabulateText())
print(tabulateText())
```

Comment: You're separately tabulating each `line in text_file`. You have a `for` (each) loop *inside your `while` loop*; the outer loop only runs once! Try moving `tabulate` *outside the `for` loop*, and get rid of the `while` altogether.

Comment: Also, note that: 1. You don't ever try to do the thing you describe in your title; and 2. finding `endline` is redundant - `\n` is (inevitably!) the last character in the line.

Comment: @jonrsharpe End is the last word in the text file I'm using as input. I want each loop to store the three columns, and after it has looped through the input document, print those values to row in the proper column order.

Answer (score 2):

The print(tabulate([column], headers..) command executes after reading the "IP address" line each time, which is why you see the headings and only one row of data.

What you can do is append each row of results (which you call "column") into an array.  This will create a table of all results. Execute the print(tabulate()) command **after** you have read all the rows of the file.

First, create an empty array before reading the text file - I'll call it table:

```
table = [] 
  with open("testinput.txt", "r") as text_file:
```

Append your column array to the table array (table.append[column]) and eliminate the print(tabulate()) command you currently have in place.

```
column = Col1[n], Col2[n], Col3[n]
table.append[column]
```

Move the print(tabulate()) command at the very end, after reading through the file and reference the new variable "table".

```
print (tabulate(table), headers=['...'])
```

You do not need the loop - the "for line" command loops through the text file.  Also, close the file when done (text_file.closed)

The function will look something like this:

```
table = []
with open("testinput.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        if "IP Address =" in line:
            start = line.find('IP Address = ')
            endline = line.find('\n', start)
            ip = line[start+13:endline]
            cert = SSLmon(ip)
            Col1 = ip
            FCS2 = cert.find('commonName')
            FCE2 = cert.find('/', FCS2)
            FCS2b = cert.find('commonName')
            FCE2b = cert.find('\n', FCS2b)
            Colopt2 = cert[FCS2+11:FCE2]
            Colopt2b = cert[FCS2b+11:FCE2b]
            Col2 = cert[FCS2+11:FCE2] if len(Colopt2) < len(Colopt2b) else cert[FCS2b+11:FCE2b]
            FCS3 = cert.find('Not valid after:')
            FCE3 = cert.find('T', FCS3)
            Col3 = cert[FCS3+18:FCE3].replace('-', '/')
            column = Col1[n], Col2[n], Col3[n]
            table.append[column]
    text_file.closed
    print(tabulate([table], headers=['IP Address', 'Common Name', 'Valid To']))
```

The table array itself will look something like this is you do a print(table) command:

[['10.0.255.250','ex.example.com','2017/02/09'],['10.0.255.251','localhost',      '2009/07/04'],['10.0.255.252','ex.example2.com','2016/05/24']]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach to get the data I wanted. I finally ended up printing each column together with padding controlled by `.ljust()` like this.

```
with open("testinput.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        if "IP Address =" in line:
            start = line.find('IP Address = ')
            endline = line.find('\n', start)
            ip = line[start+13:endline]
            cert = SSLmon(ip)
            Col1 = ip
            FCS2 = cert.find('commonName')
            FCE2 = cert.find('/', FCS2)
            FCS2b = cert.find('commonName')
            FCE2b = cert.find('\n', FCS2b)
            Colopt2 = cert[FCS2+11:FCE2]
            Colopt2b = cert[FCS2b+11:FCE2b]
            Col2 = cert[FCS2+11:FCE2] if len(Colopt2) < len(Colopt2b) else cert[FCS2b+11:FCE2b]
            FCS3 = cert.find('Not valid after:')
            FCE3 = cert.find('T', FCS3)
            Col3 = cert[FCS3+18:FCE3].replace('-', '/')
            with open(filename1, 'a') as f:
                line = '%s %s %s %s' % (Col1.ljust(20), Col2.ljust(35), Col3.ljust(15), '\n')
                f.write(line)
```